# what is the correct loop/conditional option for not finding a variable?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I am searching through three text files for one of four specific gene names (stored in `$var#`). When it is found, it takes the value found after the gene name and adds it to a count. We then average the value by taking total `$count_exp#` and dividing by the number of appearances within all files.

**What is the proper way to let the user know when a gene name is not found in each file? I'm having difficulties handling the flow of this loop/conditional.**

Here is a snippet of code that handles one of the three text files....

```
    foreach $hyperosmotic(@hyperosmotic)
{
    @hyperosmotic1=split(/\t/,$hyperosmotic);
    $name=$hyperosmotic1[0];
    $exp=$hyperosmotic1[1];
    chomp $name;
    chomp $exp;
    if ($name eq $var1)
    {
    $count_exp1 = $count_exp1 + $exp;       
    $count_var1 = ++$count_var1;    
    }
    elsif ($name eq $var2)
    {
    $count_exp2 = $count_exp2 + $exp;
    $count_var2 = ++$count_var2;    
    }
    elsif ($name eq $var3)
    {
    $count_exp3 = $count_exp3 + $exp;
    $count_var3 = ++$count_var3;    
    }
    elsif ($name eq $var4)
    {
    $count_exp4 = $count_exp4 + $exp;
    $count_var4 = ++$count_var4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `} else { $count_not_found_exp += $exp; $count_not_found_var++; }`? Not exactly sure what you are asking for

Comment: Skip all the if blocks and take amon's advice and use hashes.

Answer (score 3):

You basically want to use arrays:

(and `use strict; use warnings;`)

```
my @count_var = (0)x4;
my @count_exp = (0)x4;
my @var = ($var1, $var2, ...);

HYPEROSMOTIC:
for my $hyperosmotic (@hyperosmotic) {

    my ($name, $exp) = split /\t/, $hyperosmotic;

    for my $i (0 .. $#var) {
      if ($name eq $var[$i]) {
        $count_exp[$i] += $exp;
        $count_var[$i]++;
        next HYPEROSMOTIC; # jump into next iteration of the labeled loop
      }
    }

    # this code is only reached if no var matched:
    die qq[I don't have a var for name "$name"];
    # That just threw a fatal error. You may want to do something different.
}
```

You could improve efficiency by using hashes:

```
my %counts = (
  $var1 => {exp => 0, var => 0},
  $var2 => {exp => 0, var => 0},
  $var3 => {exp => 0, var => 0},
  $var4 => {exp => 0, var => 0},
);

for my $hyperosmotic (@hyperosmotic) {
  my ($name, $exp) = split ...;
  if (my $count = $counts{$name}) {
    $count->{exp} += $exp;
    $count->{var}++;
  } else {
    die qq[I don't have a var for name "$name"];
  }
}
```